# How can I prevent dplyr::count from ordering variables?

Tags: r, count, dplyr

I am trying to count the frequencies of correct responses to over 200 questions on an IQ test.

Responses are:

```
0 = fail
1 = correct
7 = below basal
8 = above ceiling
```

I used dplyr:group_by to put the questions into groups. This works, and retains the ordering of the variables.

```
a_long%>%
    dplyr::group_by(
        key
        , value
    ) -> a_long_grouped
```

Then I used dplyr:count to get the frequency of responses to each question.

```
a_long_count=dplyr::count(a_long_grouped
             , value
            )
```

The resulting tibble summarized the frequency of responses, but put the variables into alphabetical order, which I do not want. I've tried using sort = FALSE, but it comes out the same.

I would appreciate any suggestions -- thanks!

Comment: Please provide a _reproducible_ example. With `sort = TRUE` sorting will occur on `n`, with `sort = FALSE` sorting will be equivalent to what `summarise` does, i.e. it arranges by group. You can probably rearrange the levels of the factor first.

Comment: I think you may be unaware that `count` does the grouping behind the scenes.  If you want things in a different order, you can always `ungroup` then `arrange` afterwards.